# Filtering array of strings with predicate

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a array like:

```
{
"aaa bbb ccc",
"bbb aaa ccc",
"bbb",
"aaa ccc cbbb"
}

Query: "bbb"
```

in my app, if i use

```
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"self.title CONTAINS[cd] %@", query];
```

The result have the same order.

What i want?

```
"bbb" -
"bbb aaa ccc" -
"aaa bbb ccc" -
"aaa ccc cbbb"
```

Do you have a trick to resolve my problem.

Thanks for advance!

Comment: I guess that you're filtering, not sorting...

Comment: According to the response you want, you want to filter AND sort (and the sorting method seems to be related to "where" you saw the searched string.